# match number range with non significative zeros in zsh

Tags: zsh, regular-expression, pattern-matching, numbering

I have in a directory files like this :

```
booklet-001.pdf
booklet-002.pdf
booklet-003.pdf
…
booklet-997.pdf
booklet-998.pdf
booklet-999.pdf
```

Then, I whant to match the files numbered from 079 to 256. But how to do it with the zsh’s regex matching?

Comment: Note that filename generation (globbing) on the command line is not done with regexes in zsh (or Bash, or the POSIX shell). Both are pattern matching "languages", but the syntax and capabilities are different.

Answer (score 2):

If it's *matching* you want, as opposed to generating a list of files regardless of whether they exist or not, use the `<x-y>` glob operator:

```
print -rC1 -- booklet-<79-256>.pdf
```

`<79-256>` matches on any sequence of ASCII decimal digits that represent a number between 79 and 256 so would match on `79` or `079` or `0000000079`...

Beware that `*<79-256>.pdf` would also match on `booklet-456789.pdf` as that's `booklet-4567` followed by `89` (which matches `<79-256>`) followed by `.pdf`. Change to `(|*[^0-9])<79-256>.pdf` to match on pdf files whose root names ends in a number between 79 and 256.

For a glob that matches on `booklet-079.pdf` but not on `booklet-79.pdf` nor `booklet-0079.pdf`, use (after `set -o extendedglob`):

```
print -rC1 -- booklet-(<79-256>~^???).pdf
```

(`<79-256>` *and not not* `???`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do in zsh:

```
ls booklet-{079..256}.pdf
```

Test it, it works!

Comment: Note that it's brace expansion, not regexp matching nor zsh glob pattern matching.

Comment: and the thing with brace expansion is that it'll generate the strings in that range regardless of if they're existing filenames. E.g. if `booklet-079.pdf` didn't exist, you'd get an error message for it. And so on for each one that doesn't exist.